# Разложить данные в таблицу на сайт

Tags: php, html, css, json

Через api получил такие данные

[{"team_id":1838315,"rating":1539.59,"wins":677,"losses":341,"last_match_time":1561547432,"name":"Team Secret","tag":"Secret","logo_url":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/team_logos/1838315.png"}]

Как эти данные вывести в виде таблицы на сайт? Там таких строчек много. Я привел только одну.

Comment: парсите данные через `json_decode()`. Через `echo` выводите нужный html

Comment: @ArchDemon, спасибо за ответ. А можно небольшой пример кода с одним из пунктов? К примеру с name.

Comment: `echo '<tr><td>' . $result[0]['name'] . '</td></tr>';` или `echo '<tr><td>' . $result[0]->name . '</td></tr>';` в зависимости от парсинга в массив или объект вы выбрали

Comment: @ArchDemon можно с вами как-то связаться?

Comment: А зачем вы в пыхе это делать хотите?) Выводить `html` — старовато. Могу предположить, что нужна обработка данных на сервере, а затем отдать результат на фронт. Если так, то и отдавайте `json`.

Comment: @ doox911 я самостоятельно это не сделаю.

Comment: Тогда вам на фриланс...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sdh0-zB4o0Q тут всё ясно и без знания английского